# How to install IIS Express 8 and SQL Server 2012 using WiX?

Tags: sql-server, iis, wix, sql-server-express, iis-express

I want to create an installer using WiX, which will install following pieces of software, if they aren't installed already:

1. installs IIS Server Express 8.0
2. SQL Server 2012 Express.

To do this, I created following `Setup.wxs` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*"
        Name="Your Application"
        Language="1033"
        Version="1.0.0.0"
        UpgradeCode="6431D91E-AD61-4FBB-A081-B63A0E416888"
        Manufacturer="Your Company">
        <Package Description="#Description"
            Comments="Comments"
            InstallerVersion="200"
            Compressed="yes"/>      
        <!-- Installation directory and files are defined in Files.wxs -->
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"/>

        <!--
            Using the Wix UI library.

            WixUI_Minimal is the most basic of the WixUI stock dialog sets.
            Its sole dialog combines the welcome and license-agreement 
            dialogs and omits the feature customization dialog. 
            WixUI_Minimal is appropriate when your product has no optional 
            features.
        -->
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal"/>

        <Binary Id="Iis"  
                SourceFile="D:\dev\wix-installer\ref\iis-8-express\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_de-DE.msi" />

        <Binary Id="SqlServer"  
                SourceFile="D:\dev\wix-installer\ref\sql-server-2012-express\SQLEXPR_x64_DEU.exe" />

    <CustomAction 
        Id="InstallIis" 
        Impersonate="no" 
        Execute="deferred" 
        BinaryKey="Iis" 
        ExeCommand="D:\dev\wix-installer\ref\iis-8-express\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_de-DE.msi" 
        Return="asyncWait" />
    <CustomAction 
        Id="InstallSqlServer" 
        Impersonate="no" 
        Execute="deferred" 
        BinaryKey="SqlServer" 
        ExeCommand="D:\dev\wix-installer\ref\sql-server-2012-express\SQLEXPR_x64_DEU.exe" 
        Return="asyncWait" />

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="InstallIis" After="InstallInitialize"/>
            <Custom Action="InstallSqlServer" After="InstallIis"/>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

The `Files.wxs` file contains following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
</Wix>
```

When I run `msiexec /l*v "log.txt" /i Installer.msi`, I get a message that there was a failure during the installation. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11776689/2013_11_23_wix_log.txt) is the contents of the `log.txt` file.

How should I modify the WiX files in order for them to install IIS and SQL Server by executing the files `iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_de-DE.msi` and `SQLEXPR_x64_DEU.exe`?

Comment: You can start from here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/

Comment: Have you considered to build a bundle package, as Yan suggested? It's quite easy to include third-party software such as .Net or the SQL Server in a bundle package