# WiX 3.8 Installing IIS Express and SQL Server LocalDB 2012

Tags: iis, wix, iis-express, iis-8, wix3.8

I am trying to build a bootstraper application with WiX 3.8 that will install IIS Express 8 and sql server 2012. I saw the link below but they arent using a bundle and the answer is only for parts of sql 2012 that I dont really need. All of the "tutorials" i have found seem extremely outdated - based on old versions of wix. Does anyone have any suggestions? This is as far as I have gotten. I also cant seem to find anyway to install IIS or SQL Server or LocalDB silently with an answer file or something similar. The end goal is to provide no UI outside of wix for these installs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="" UpgradeCode="668b68ed-5274-4413-984d-72959e8e211a">
     <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
     <Chain>
  <MsiPackage
    Name="IIS Express 8"
    Cache="no" 
    Compressed="yes" 
    Permanent="yes" 
    Vital="yes"
    DisplayInternalUI="yes"
    SourceFile="F:\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi" />
  <ExePackage
    Name="SQL Server Express 2012"
    Cache="no" 
    Compressed="yes" 
    Permanent="yes" 
    Vital="yes"
    SourceFile="F:\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" />
  <MsiPackage
    Name="SQL LocalDB"
    Cache="no" 
    Compressed="yes" 
    Permanent="yes" 
    Vital="yes"
    DisplayInternalUI="yes"
    SourceFile="F:\SQLLocalDB.msi" />  
     </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

[How to install IIS Express 8 and SQL Server 2012 using WiX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089146/how-to-install-iis-express-8-and-sql-server-2012-using-wix)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     >



  <Bundle Name="MyApp" Version="1.0" Manufacturer="ACME">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
      <bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseUrl=""  />
      <Payload SourceFile="Resources\LogoSide.png" />
      <Payload SourceFile="Resources\Logo.png" />     
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <WixVariable Id="SuppressOptionsUI" Value="Yes"/>

    <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeXml" Value="Resources\Bundle2Theme.xml" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixExtbaThemeWxl" Value="Resources\HyperlinkTheme.wxl" />

    <Chain>           
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx46Redist"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="LocalDb64"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="LocalDb"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="IISExpress64"/>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="IISExpress86"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
     <bal:Condition Message="Requires windows 7 or higher">VersionNT &gt;= v6.1</bal:Condition>  
    <PackageGroup Id="IISExpress64">
      <MsiPackage
       Id="IISExpress64"
       Name="IIS Express 8"
       Cache="no"
       Compressed="no"
       Permanent="yes"
       Vital="yes"
       DisplayInternalUI="yes"     
       SourceFile=".\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi" 
       InstallCondition="VersionNT64" />  
    </PackageGroup>
    <PackageGroup Id="IISExpress86">
      <MsiPackage
        Id="IISExpress86"
        Name="IIS Express 8"
       Cache="no"
       Compressed="no"
       Permanent="yes"
       Vital="yes"
       DisplayInternalUI="yes"
       SourceFile=".\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x86_en-US.msi"
       InstallCondition="NOT VersionNT64" />
    </PackageGroup>

    <PackageGroup Id="LocalDb64">
      <MsiPackage Id="SqlServerLocalDb64bit"
                        DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Visible="yes"
                        Compressed="no"
                        EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
                        Vital="yes"
                        SourceFile=".\SqlLocaLDBx64.MSI"
                        DownloadUrl="{2}"
                        InstallCondition="NOT LocalDbInstalled AND VersionNT64" >
        <MsiProperty Name="IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS" Value="YES" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </PackageGroup>
    <PackageGroup Id="LocalDb">
      <MsiPackage Id="SqlServerLocalDb32bit"                  
                        DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Visible="yes"
                        Compressed="no"
                        EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
                        Vital="yes"
                        SourceFile=".\SqlLocaLDBx86.MSI"
                        DownloadUrl="{2}"
                        InstallCondition="NOT LocalDbInstalled AND NOT VersionNT64" >
        <MsiProperty Name="IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS" Value="YES" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```